# Making events fire in iE6 while <select> is active and dropped down

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am pretty sure this is just a limitation of IE6, but I thought I better ask just in case:

```
<body>
    <h1>Select + event test</h1>
    <div>   
        <select>
            <option>ABC</option>
            <option>123</option>
        </select>
        <span id="eventSrc">Event Source</span>
    </div>
    <div id="log"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var log = $("#log");
        $("#eventSrc").bind("mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave", function(event){
            log.append(event.type + "<br/>");
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

In all modern browsers, the log registers mouse* events, even when the select is "dropped down". In IE6, it doesn't seem to fire the events while active + dropped down.

Any solutions?  My use-case is for tooltips that need to popup on `mouseover`, even when looking at the dropdown list..

Pure JS solutions also welcome, jQuery is just concise for my demo :)

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do this...IE6 using the winforms element pretty much screwed up all sorts of stuff...but hey hopefully someone can prove otherwise with a neat trick.

Comment: I modified my code to use the iE specific "attachEvent" directly, and the same (fail)result:





 <script type="text/javascript">
  var log = $("#log");
  var eSrc = $("#eventSrc").get(0);
  
  eSrc.attachEvent("onmouseover", function(){
   log.append("event<br/>");
  })
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

I think you are out of luck.  IE has notoriously had issues with select lists.

e.g. [you can't bind events to the options](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html) in a select list... or [disable them](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-293-cant-disable-options-in-ie.html) (pre IE8)  and [trying to modify the contents](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2009/02/bug-487-onclickonfocus-bugs-on-select.html) (e.g. options) while it is open fails.